# Cannot load remote URL inside body using TbModal widget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, modal-dialog, yii-extensions

It seems that I cannot get TbModal widget to load a remote URL (another controller/view combination).

This is the view that's creating the modal:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'myModal')); ?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h4>Client Ticket Log</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type'=>'primary',
        'label'=>'Save changes',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label'=>'Close',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Click me',
    'type'=>'primary',
    'url'=> array('clientticketlog/create', 'ticket_id'=>$model->id),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'data-toggle'=>'modal',
        'data-target'=>'#myModal',
    ),
)); ?>
```

As I understand from the documentation, if the href attribute is provided in the link that calls the modal, jQuery will load the content of that address in the modal body.

But it doesn't and the body remains empty. I've checked the URL I'm trying to load by opening it in a separate tab and it load's as it should.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: as far as i know using href does not auto populate the modal body I would suggest using renderPartial to display the content within the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Manquer is right. `href` doesn't populate the modal. His suggestion works if the content of the modal doesn't change. If you want to reuse the same modal for a different view, however, you need to use javascript e.g:

```
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if(url){
        $(target).find(".modal-body").load(url);
    }
});
```